# How To make the popup stay on the same area after close

Tags: javascript, scroll, popup

I got this popup that when you scroll down to the bottom of the page and click the close button, it scrolls the user to the top of the page

here's what it looks like:

```
<a href="#" onClick="stpFlush();" id="stp-close">X</a>
```

whole javascript code: http://palimashop.com/wp-content/plugins/social-traffic-pop/stp.js?ver=1.0

I would like the user to not get redirected to the top of the page after close. how do we do that?

I would appreciate any help. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it sounds like the JS function isn't stopping the postback of clicking the link, add a `return false;` to the end of `stpFlush`.  It also may be worth putting `action.stopPropagation()` at the start of the function too.

Answer (score 1):

You can make to position fixed on the screen no matter where you are on the page.

**Via CSS**

```
#stp-close { /* Probably you need to use stp-main ! */
    position: fixed;
}
```

You may need to set another selector if `stp-close` is not used for the popup. I might be `#stp-main` from what I can see in the JS.